# PHP not finding extensions in the correct directory

Tags: php

Sorry if this is a repeat of another question; my searches failed to find a direct solution to my problem.

Just now, my machine updated PHP to v8.2. Since then, I have been unable to run the SQL Server extension.

After some trial and error, I got the INI files copied to the new folder, as confirmed by `php -i` (trimmed for brevity):

```
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-sqlsrv.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
...
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini
```

When I run `php -i`, this warning appears:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20220829/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Okay... I can find the files manually:

```
/usr/lib/php find . -name sqlsrv*
./20210902/sqlsrv.so
/usr/lib/php find . -name pdo_sqlsrv*
./20210902/pdo_sqlsrv.so
```

Clearly they aren't where PHP is looking for them. But how do I make PHP find them?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the extensions

sockets, sqlsrv, sysvmsg, xsl, pdo_sqlsrv

are not installed for php 8.2.

Please install them, probably by doing

```
sudo apt-get install php8.2-sockets
etc
```

Each php version has its own .so extension directory under /usr/lib/php/

[image]

In each folder there are compiled versions of extensions for each php version.

A compiled extension(.so file) will not work with a different php version.